# Show that $\sinh^2[2^{j-1}\cosh^{-1}( 2)]+1$ is still a natural number for all natural numbers $j$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Show that this real number $$\sinh^2[2^{j-1}\cosh^{-1}( 2)]+1$$ is still a natural number for all natural numbers $j$.

Comment: are you sure that this is true?

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: Yes, for the first small natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$a_j =\sinh^2[2^{j-1}\cosh^{-1}( 2)]$$
Then we have $a_1=3$ and the result that $a_j\;$ and your numbers $a_j+1\;$ are integers for $j>1\;$ follows from

$$a_{j+1}=\sinh^2[2\times2^{j-1}\cosh^{-1}( 2)]$$
$$=\Big(\sinh[2\times2^{j-1}\cosh^{-1}( 2)]\Big)^2$$
$$=\Big(2\sinh[2^{j-1}\cosh^{-1}( 2)]\cosh[2^{j-1}\cosh^{-1}( 2)]\Big)^2$$
$$=4\sinh^2[2^{j-1}\cosh^{-1}( 2)]\cosh^2[2^{j-1}\cosh^{-1}( 2)]$$
$$=4\sinh^2[2^{j-1}\cosh^{-1}( 2)]\Big(1+\sinh^2[2^{j-1}\cosh^{-1}( 2)]\Big)$$
$$=4a_j(1+a_j)$$
And this is obviously an integer if $a_j$ is an integer. Here I have used the double angle formula
$$\sinh 2x = 2 \sinh x \cosh x$$
and the property
$$\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1$$